# Using SQL, how can I create a new table from a 2d array that's a comma separated list?

Tags: sql, tableau-api

TL;DR I have a table with a single column that contains a 2 dimensional array where one of the dimensions is of variable length. I'm trying to figure out how to turn it into a table where each array dimension is a column.

Background:
I have a system for tracking production-line quality and for the defective items, it records both the defect location(s) and the defect type(s) found on the item. In my DB, both the locations and the types are stored in a single column as a 2-dimensional array. A given item can have an unknown number of defect locations and in each location, there can be no less than 1 & no more than 9 types of defects marked off. For example: A shirt might have 22 points that are checked by the quality control person and in the 8 locations that had problems, the inspector marked between 1 & 9 defect types.

Example records:

```
ITEM: 1, [[Location: A; Type: 1], [Location: B, Type: 2]]   
ITEM: 2, [[Location: A; Type: 1,4], [Location: B, Type: 6]] 
ITEM: 3, [[Location: A; Type: 3], [Location: B, Type: 2,1,6], [Location: C, Type: 3]
```

I'm having difficulty figuring out how to split this column into a usable form. Additionally, I'm not sure how to deal with the fact that for each item, it can have a large (and unknown) number of defect locations.

Example desired output: (a new table with columns ITEM, Location, & Type)

```
ITEM: 1, Location: A, Type: 1  
ITEM: 1, Location: B, Type: 2  
ITEM: 2, Location: A, Type: 1  
ITEM: 2, Location: A, Type: 4  
ITEM: 2, Location: B, Type: 6  
ITEM: 3, Location: A, Type: 3
```

and so on...

This is doable in python but I don't know how to do it in SQL:

```
// a, b, c are sample rows from my DB
a = [{"types":[{"N":4}],"defectId":"fafd9dfe-e4e4-4179-86cb-1e43d428c4d4"}]
b = [{"types":[{"N":5}],"defectId":"198074a8-66c2-4c8f-84f7-b51e6f6daac5"},{"types":[{"N":9}],"defectId":"e1e38dd0-6ba4-446f-a295-c75430776d3c"},{"types":[{"N":2}],"defectId":"a90d66cd-ec87-4a02-b3b8-82a5516ec6d0"},{"types":[{"N":7}],"defectId":"494476f8-4dfc-4306-84c5-ab090a8f9967"}]
c = [{"types":[{"N":3},{"N":5}],"defectId":"e1e38dd0-6ba4-446f-a295-c75430776d3c"}]

array = [a, b, c]
print("item stats id, defect id (location), defect type")
itemNum = 1
for row in array:
    for item in row:
        types = item["types"]
        for i in range(len(types)):
            print(itemNum.__str__() + ", " + item["defectId"] + ", " + types[i]["N"].__str__())
    itemNum += 1

'''
item stats id              defect id (location)                    defect type
1               e1e38dd0-6ba4-446f-a295-c75430776d3c                    3
1               e1e38dd0-6ba4-446f-a295-c75430776d3c                    4
'''
```

Comment: In the end I changed the data model that I was sending to the ODBC and broke the column into a new table.

Answer (score 0):

There's the VALUES keyword, there is also the IN operator which works like that.

VALUES(1,2,3) or IN(1,2,3)

But your question seems more suited for a join on itself.

I would probably nest the query and join it to itself, see http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_self.asp